# Estoy intentando crear un nuevo usuario cuando no existe en la base de datos JSON

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json

Estoy intentando, en Node.js, coger una cantidad de dinero random la cual la genera "moneye" y sumarla (el dinero de moneye + el dinero que ya tenía en la base de datos) al usuario que haya realizado la acción. El problema lo tengo en que, si el usuario que ha hecho la interacción no consta en la base de datos, el archivo JS crea uno con su id y su dinero
= 0 + el dinero que haya ganado.

**Codigo JS**

```
  var moneya = []
            Object.keys(file_users.users).forEach(user => {
                moneya.push(file_users.users[user].Money)
                var moneye = file_users.users[user].Money
                var moneytotal = moneye + moneywin
                const nel = interaction.user.id
                if (nel != file_users.users) {
                    let joc1 = {
                        ID: interaction.user.id,
                        Money: 0
                    };

                    function UpdateMoneyById2(id2, new22) {
                        file_users.push(x => x.users == id2).users = new22;
                    }
                    UpdateMoneyById2(users, joc1);

                }

                function UpdateMoneyById(id, newMoney) {
                    file_users.users.find(x => x.ID == id).Money = newMoney;
                }
                UpdateMoneyById(nel, moneytotal);

                fs.writeFile('C:/Users/aleix/OneDrive/Escritorio/Terranoids/functions/prova1.json', JSON.stringify(file_users, null, 4), (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error writing file: $ { err }");
                    }
                });
            })
```

**Base de datos JSON**

```
{
    "users": [{
            "ID": "509000419935125544",
            "Money": 9194
        },
        {
            "ID": "333",
            "Money": 9191
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tenes aqui: `file_users.users.find(x => x.ID == id).Money`

Obviamente si el usuario no existe, el find() te devuelve un null que no tiene  la prop Money. Yo lo separaría de esta manera:

```
function UpdateMoneyById(id, newMoney) {
  const user = file_users.users.find(x => x.ID == id)
  if(user) user.Money = newMoney;
}
```